# Entity Framework 6 with Oracle 10g problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, oracle10g

I try to import stored procedures from an Oracle 10g database using an Entity Framework 6 database-first  approach but after I import stored procedures from the database and then I open Oracle SQL developer to open the imported stored procedures and I found in just "create or replace " in source code for all stored procedures on the same schema even the ones I didn't import by entity framework in my project why this happens and how to overcome

Answer (score 0):

After I have search I discovered it's better to use ADO.NET with Oracle 10G database and if you want to have entity framwork experience with Oracle database there is one paid third party library called Devart.Data.Oracle.EF6